# Set auto id to primary key column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and primary key is already set to that table and now I want that column to be autoincrement. Table has many records. Is it possible? or which one is fastest way to do that?

Comment: In short: it cannot be done to an existing column, please see the link above for workarounds

Comment: What's wrong with your current primary key?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make some effort for this as you cannot create identity column on existing column. However you may have a workaround for this like first try this to add a new column having identity field:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_name
   ADD ID INT IDENTITY
```

and then make your ID as primary key like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_name
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable
   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
```

And yes you have to remove the old dependencies before performing the above steps like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Table1_Col1
```

**EDIT:-**

From the [source](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/252226/allow-enabling-and-disabling-of-a-columns-identity-property):

We can use **ALTER TABLE...SWITCH** to work around this by only modifying metadata. See Books Online for restrictions on using the SWITCH method presented below. The process is practically instant even for the largest tables.

```
USE tempdb;
GO
-- A table with an identity column
CREATE TABLE dbo.Source (row_id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, data SQL_VARIANT NULL);
GO
-- Some sample data
INSERT dbo.Source (data) 
VALUES (CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, 4)), 
        (CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, 'X')), 
        (CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, {d '2009-11-07'})),
        (CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, N'áéíóú'));
GO
-- Remove the identity property
BEGIN TRY;
    -- All or nothing
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- A table with the same structure as the one with the identity column,
    -- but without the identity property
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Destination (row_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, data SQL_VARIANT NULL);

    -- Metadata switch
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Source SWITCH TO dbo.Destination;

    -- Drop the old object, which now contains no data
    DROP TABLE dbo.Source;

    -- Rename the new object to make it look like the old one
    EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Destination', N'Source', 'OBJECT';

    -- Success
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Bugger!
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;
GO

-- Test the the identity property has indeed gone
INSERT dbo.Source (row_id, data)
VALUES (5, CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, N'This works!'))

SELECT row_id,
        data
FROM    dbo.Source;
GO

-- Tidy up
DROP TABLE dbo.Source;
```

Comment: you've missed the "remove old key and dependencies" step